# Excel formula to find duplicate value and copy the adjacent cell data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula to first locate a duplicate value in **column A**, and once found then copy the values from the adjacent columns B and C...The goal is to have all values for those columns identical.

Example of output (first and last rows):

```
  A      B        C
930153  ABCD    TEST1
931364  EFGH    TEST2
931288  IJKL    TEST3
930153  ABCD    TEST1
```

Comment: So you want to put a formula in the cells that would copy cells in the same column where column A matches?  If so, this is not possible, You will need to put the formula in separate columns.

Comment: Overall, the goal is to find duplicate values in column A, and have those duplicates identically show the same values in columns B&C. I was thinking of on an IF function  (i.e., IF column A is equal to a value in the same column, then copy the values of the adjacent columns into B&C). I can paste the formula down column D even and hide the column, as long as it compares the values and copies the proper data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood your comment right, the simplest solution would be

```
=VLOOKUP($A1,$A$1:$C1,2,0)
```

It just looks up the the value from current row in column `A` up to current row and gets the value from column 2 or 3 of the first matched line. You have to adapt the `2`.

For the given sample data, this

```
=VLOOKUP($A1,$A$1:$C1,column()-2,0)
```

would be an automatic solution for the column.

You can pull the formula downwards and sideways.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, this worked. I needed to adjust it a bit as you mentioned, but I was able to finish my project. Thanks for the assist on this!